# Simply use React State Management with Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to figure out what the simplest way to use React state management with the react-router. The Router works great with a state container like Redux, but what if you wanted to use React to manage your state? What if you want to store state in a single root component and pass it to child components explicitly as props. And, you want the code to look pretty and be efficient?

The simplest solution would be to use the Router as a child child component, but I know it don't work like this:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { Catalog, Cart, Checkout } from './shopping'
import { Menu, Errors } from './navigation'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inventoy: [ ... ],
      cart: [ ... ]           
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Menu />
        <Router history={hashHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={Catalog} inventory={inventory} />
          <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} cart={cart} />
        </Router>
        <Errors />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('target'))
```

So it seems that the router wants to be the parent, and the approach would be nested routes. But to do that you have to clone elements and explicitly pass all of the state variables to all of the children:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import { Catalog, Cart, Checkout } from './shopping'
import { Menu, Errors } from './navigation'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inventoy: [ ... ],
            cart: [ ... ]
        }
    }

    render() {

        const { children } = this.props
        const { inventory, cart } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="app">
                <Menu />
                {React.cloneElement(children, {inventory, cart})}
                <Errors />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="/" component={Catalog} />
            <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('target')
)
```

The problem this this approach is that extra data is being passed to the nested components. The Cart component doesn't need inventory, but it gets it anyways. The Catalog component doesn't need the cart data but it get's it anyways. Obviously this can get out of control with a lot of state and a lot of state data. Also cloning components doesn't seem so efficient.

Is there something that I am missing, is there an easier way to pass state from a root component to a child component using the router, or do you always have to use a state container like redux when working with the router?

React state is kind of nice, the react-router is kind of nice. Is there a better way to use them together? Is the router simple enough for beginners to easily incorporate?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution for very simple routing. That is to reuse the same component for different routes, and within the component display the approprate elements by checking location.pathname or params.

```
render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/cart" component={App} />
        <Route path="/catalog/:category" component={App} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('target')
)
```

Everything renders the app component, but you can use the router props in the App's render mehtod.

```
render() {
    var currentLocation = this.props.location.pathname
    var category = this.props.params.category
}
```